# text selection AND bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selection

this is the problem:
I'm using javascript and JQuery (not UI) to drag nested objects in my web page.
to disable the text selecting I have to return FALSE from the mousedown handler, but this disable also the event bubbling. But I need event bubbling...
What can I do??
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution for disabling text selection is css user-select:

```
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

Although, I don't think it works in IE.

Another thought might be (if your layout allows) to overlay your text with an invisible div. This should prevent text selection.

```
<div class='textbox'>text box<div class='overlay'></div></div>

        .textbox {
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .overlay {      
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;left:0;
        }
```